# 2 outputs being shown, one wrong and the other correct

Tags: mips, branch

Trying to implement the polynomial, 3x^2 - 4x + 1, into MIPS assembly. I have a constraint of 0 <= x <= 7. However, when I try testing all conditions, all but one of the 3 conditions is outputting something completely unexpected.

```
.data
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter number between 0 and 7: "
    result: .asciiz "The result after putting it throught 3x^2 - 4x + 1 is: "
    message: .asciiz "What you put was below 0.\n"
    message2: .asciiz "What you put was over 7.\n"
.text
.globl main

main:
    
    #Prompt user to enter number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall
    
    #Get user input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    #Store result in $t0
    move $t0, $v0
    
    #sets up a constant for boolean conditions
    li $t1, 7
    
    #If $t0 is less than 0 it will tell the user the number is below 0
    blez $t0, under
    bge $t0, $t1, over
    #If $t0 is greater than $t1, the program goes to over
    
    

    
Poly:
#This equals to 3(x^2) - 4x + 1
    #Display result string
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall
    
    #squaring number
    mult $t0, $t0
    
    #moves the product to $s0
    mflo $s0 #moves the product from lo to $s0
    move $t2, $s0 #moves product to $t2
    
    #multiply the square with 3
    li $t3, 3 #sets up constant
    mult $t2, $t3 #multiplies constant with $t2
    mflo $s0 #like last time move the product to $s0
    move $t3, $s0 #moves the product to $t3
    
    # multiply user input with 4
    li $t4, 4 #Sets uo constant
    mult $t0, $t4 #multiply the variable with the constant
    mflo $s0 #you already know what happens for the next two lines
    move $t4, $s0
    
    #Subtracts $t4 and $t3
    sub $t5, $t3, $t4 #subtracts the last two products from each other and store it to $t5
    
    #adds 1 to $t5
    li $t6, 1 #sets up constant
    add $t0, $t5, $t6 #adds the difference of $t3 and $t4 and adds them to one and stores it at $t0
    
    #displays the product
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $zero, $t0 #prints the result of the polynomial
    syscall #ends program
    
under:
#This label will tell the user to enter another number under the contraints this time around
    #Display the wrong statement
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message
    syscall
    
    j main
    
over:
#This label will tell the user to enter another number under the contraints this time around
    #Display the wrong statement
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message2
    syscall
    
    j main
```

[two outputs being shown. What is this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7VTX.png)

I expected to see just result and what the product of the expression is.

Comment: You should be able to find this problem yourself by single step debugging.  Broadly speaking, single step works the same in assembly as in other languages.  Step line-by-line and verify that (1) the program state is properly updated as expected, validating computation, and (2) the next line to run is the proper and expected one, validating the control flow.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this piece of code where you print the result:

```
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $zero, $t0 #prints the result of the polynomial
syscall #ends program
```

The comment suggests that you want to end execution of your program. But that's not what you're doing; you're just printing an integer value.

So right after this (before `under:`) you need to perform a system call 10 ("exit"):

```
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Some people call C "portable assembly", I call assembly "non-portable BASIC." In the sense that there is only GOTO and execution always falls through unless you say otherwise.